# Hiding objects in unity without changing their state

Tags: unity3d-editor

I have a vague memory of a Unity video tutorial where the guy hid some objets while building a scene. The thing is that he dind't use the usual 'disable/enable the object via the inspector checkbox' and so he didn't have to worry to enable them later... moreover, as the objects were 'invisible but enabled', all attached behaviours were working.

As far as I remember the effect was pretty similar to moving the object into a hidden layer (but not changing the object layer but using a different Unity built-in action so he actually dind't change anything in the object).

I've been trying to remember how he did such a thing and looking around the editor to find the specific option but with no luck. Honestly, I'm beginnig to think that I might not be remembering correctly. Do anyone know about this 'hide objects without changing them' command?

Regards!

Comment: He May Created custom Editor Script which runs on Editor

Comment: Thanks friend. 
That would certainly do the trick but as far as I remember it was something already built-in in Unity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just received by chance a link to a video on twitter (I think it's the very same I was trying to remember but I'm not 100% sure). Anyway it seems that my current Unity version 2018.3.3) doesn't include that 'Scene visibility' toggle; it seems to be available for 2019 Beta. . I didn't test it yet but it seems pretty straightforward, just click on a gray bar in the hierarchy bar, to the left of the object you want to 'hide'; the bar seems to work as a an visible/not visible toggle. [Here a link to de video](https://youtu.be/VCQbFjLWaHQ?t=180) where you can see the thing working!

I hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like he might have just turned the object's renderer off. Each GaneObject is going to have some kind of renderer as a property in the inspector (sprite renderer if its 2D, ect). He probably just disabled that as opposed to disabling the entire GameObject. Let me know if that helps!

Comment: Hi friend. That would do more or less the same thing but it will also change the state of some game object's component. It's an useful trick but not what I'm looking for
Anyway thanks for the suggestion :)